# Finding the area of an ellipse using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am new to linear algebra. If my answer is incorrect tips would be appreciated!

> Q1: Find the area of an ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{16} + \dfrac{y^2}{25} = 1$ with linear algebra.

My work:

$b = 5$

$a = 4$

Therefore the matrix is $A = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 5\end{pmatrix}$.

$\det A = ad - bc  = (4)5 + 0  = 20$

Now, $20$ is just area of one section of the ellipse, I assume that I have to multiple by $4$ because there are four sections. Is this the correct idea? Thanks! I appreciate all the help!

Comment: This is an assignment which I have given as homework. Please do not answer this. My students should come to me for help.

Comment: @Jeff, with all due respect, the OP has clearly thought about the problem, given the work (and partial answer) provided thus far; asking people not to give the clarification sought by the OP is to diminish the spirit of collaboration that makes this site the powerful source that it is.

Comment: Do you know what the area of the specified ellipse is?  Perhaps knowing what the answer is supposed to be will help with knowing how to apply the specified method...

Comment: @dleggas  While I take your point, this particular assignment is technically a take-home **quiz**. Certainly you agree that questions from take-home quizzes and exams should not be answered on this website?

Comment: Also, the user has already asked another question which was completely answered for him/her. Clarifications are one thing (and easily obtained my emailing me). Solutions are a different matter.

Comment: @Jeff I personally believe it's OK to give hints (like in my "answer" below. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I'm ok with hints, and I like yours. What I'm concerned about are full solutions.

Comment: I guess it's impractical for me to hope to police this entire site, so never mind. I have external ways to deal with this situation.

Comment: @Jeff, I agree that seeking an outright solution seems unfair given that this is a quiz; point well taken. On the other hand, it must be acknowledged to some extent that people will use a variety of resources when given such forms of examination; the internet is full of information. I agree that external policing will be more successful in your situation. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint to the OP (which should satisfy @Jeff, because it's not an outright solution):

Remember that the transformation is something that's applied to a *unit circle* to transform it into an ellipse. You need to take the enclosed area of the unit circle into account to get your final answer. $\pi$ needs to appear somewhere in there, wouldn't you say?

Comment: I see, that does make a lot of sense. I will definitely take that into account. Thank you for the tip!